# Endless Django websocket

Tags: django, websocket

There is a page that has a button that I can click and initiate the process on the server via Websocket. I get information about process via Websocket. How can I close and reopen the page to see the current status of the process, not at first, without a disconnect?

```
async def worker_status(send):
for i in range(numbers):
    some_function()
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def websocket_application(scope, receive, send):
while True:
    event = await receive()
    if event['type'] == 'websocket.connect':
        await send({
            'type': 'websocket.accept'
        })
    if event['type'] == 'websocket.disconnect':
        break
    if event['type'] == 'websocket.receive':
        if event['text'] == 'StartAct':
            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
            loop.create_task(worker_status())
            await send({
                'type': 'websocket.send',
                'text': str("In process")
            })
        if event['text'] == 'Status':
            await send({
                'type': 'websocket.send',
                'text': str("Ready to process")
            })
```

Comment: Websockets are already persistent connections unless disconnected. Please provide code and exact problem.

Comment: That's right! But if it's disconnect ant reconnect again